# Core.jar not in Zxing Core folder? - Zxing Barcode Scanner

Tags: java, android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am trying to follow through with the instructions given on Stack with regards to embedding the Zxing barcode scanner technology without the user having to download the app from the google play store.

I have read that you must copy the "Core.jar" file from the Core folder from the latest version of Zxing library on GitHub. I have downloaded the latest library from GitHub but there is no sign of the Core.jar file??

Can anyone provide me with instructions on how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-qr-code-scanner-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks I will give this tutorial a go as well :) @Prem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to download ZXing .jar file for Android.

You can download that from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/android-core/3.2.0/android-core-3.2.0.jar).

Further details: [Getting started developing: ZXING | GitHub](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Getting-Started-Developing)